# Trying to make a picturebox drag but it glitches out C#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void Brick_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isDragging = true;
    } 
    private void Brick_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            Brick1.Left = e.X;
            Brick1.Top = e.Y;
        }
    }
    public void Brick_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs m)
    {
        isDragging = false;
    }
```

It kinda works but it glitches out when you move it (The picturebox teleports around the screen rapidly). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWazyAnGNBE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `PointToClient` method of the `Form`

```
var relativePoint = this.PointToClient(new Point(X, Y));

// Or

var relativePoint = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```

[Control.PointToClient Method (Point)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Computes the location of the specified screen point into client
>   coordinates.

Update

```
private void Brick_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDragging)
    {
        var relativePoint = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        Brick1.Left = relativePoint.X;
        Brick1.Top = relativePoint.Y;
    }
}
```